# Как получить все номера домов из google api?

Tags: android, google-places-api

Есть такой вопрос: в своем приложении для поиска адреса использую *google places api*, и мне нужно получить все номера улицы которую ввел пользователь.

Как это сделать?

Comment: Вы на русской версии сайта.